# React-Router: Achieving the same goal of <IndexRoute> in v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently following a video that is using v3 of react-router (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Smk2FusU_70) and the author is using `<IndexRoute>`. I'm using v4 and can't use it anymore.

I am trying to render `App` when I goto `/` and then render `Custom` when I goto `/Custom`.

The code below does **not** work.

How should I modify it so `App` is included inside of `/` and when I goto `/Custom` it also includes `/`?

Thanks!

My index.js

```
const Routes = props => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Container} >
                    <Route path='app' component={App} />
                    <Route path='custom' component={Custom} />
                </Route>

                <Route path='*'>
                    <Redirect to='/' />
                </Route>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Container.js

```
class Container extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p className="App-intro">
        To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
      </p>
    );
  }
}
```

Full code here - https://gist.github.com/RubikCubes/b4015b867d76527a063cd3e25144ca41

Comment: nested routes are no longer allowed in v4, to rewrite that, simply have the routes as siblings of one another or render the child routes as children within another component

Comment: yea, i'm not quite sure how to do that....

Answer (score 0):

Nest the routes inside the Container component, and use [`match.path`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) to get the pattern used in the container, and combine it with the children's path ([working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/7kk430m66j)):

```
class Container extends Component {
    render() {
        const { children, match } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>

                    <div>
                        <Route exact path={match.path} component={App} />
                        <Route path={`${match.path}custom`} component={Custom} />
                    </div>
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And this is how Routes should look:

```
const Routes = props => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route path='/' component={Container} />

                <Route path='*'>
                    <Redirect to='/' />
                </Route>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Comment: the full code - https://gist.github.com/RubikCubes/b4015b867d76527a063cd3e25144ca41

Comment: huh, thats weird. even when i hit the `custom` link and refresh, it redirects back to `app`

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
class Container extends Component {
    render() {
        const { children, match } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>

                </header>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
                    <Route path="/custom" component={Custom} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```